# PHP 5.4.* already comes with xdebug installed?

Tags: 12.10, php, xdebug

Ubuntu 12.10 fresh install here.

So I just installed php with `sudo apt-get install php5` + a few other packages like php5-curl. I executed `php -v` and noticed something pretty bizarre:

```
PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1 (cli) (built: Nov 15 2012 01:18:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

Notice the Xdebug extension installed? I did not install it through apt (`php5-xdebug` package), neither through pecl and neither from source!

Question. On Ubuntu, does PHP already comes with xdebug now?

Comment: Did you previously have xdebug installed and did you update php or do clean install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marcio,

you might have accidentaly installed `php5-xdebug` as a dependency of some other package.

The default clean php5-cli installation just gives:

```
# php5 -v
PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2 (cli) (built: Mar 11 2013 14:57:54) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

You can check installed binary modules in `/usr/lib/php5/20100525` directory and then you can use `dpkg -S` to query the coresponding debian package (I have installed php5-xdebug manually meanwhile):

```
# dpkg -S /usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so 
php5-xdebug: /usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so
```

If this doesn't show up anything then it means that somebody (or some automatic script) has installed the xdebug without you knowing.